# Angularjs is not updating ng-model value when the value of dropdown/select is being changed

Tags: angularjs-ng-model, jquery-events, angularjs-ng-change, angularjs-events

When i am changing my option value of select it's ng-model value is not being changed.
Is this happening because of value is being changed by Jquery?
Because i read a line about angularjs  from w3school that The ng-change event is only triggered if there is a actual change in the input value, and not if the change was made from a JavaScript.

And i want to clarify that option value is being changed by j query.

Please suggest me proper solution  or  tell me error in the code.

Here is my html

```
<div class="row" ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mycontroller" id="mainController">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Rooms
                <% no_of_rooms %>
            </p>
            <select ng-init="no_of_rooms='1'" autocomplete="off" ng-model="no_of_rooms" class="form-control" id="no_of_rooms" style='display:none' name="no_of_room" style="height: 39px !important;">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(no_of_rooms) track by $index">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p>Adult (12+ YRS)</p>
            <select autocomplete="off" class="form-control" style='display:none' name="no_of_adults[]" style="height: 39px !important;">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1" Selected>1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
app.controller('mycontroller', function($scope , $filter) {
 $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(parseInt(num));   
    }
});
```

Comment: Your using two select-box and those are hiding from screen.Could you please explain why you are hiding the select box. on which event your changing the value.

Comment: cause js is being applied on these and  ul and li is being generated and i don't want to show both.